# tcpflow alternative for UDP

Tags: linux, udp, pcap

I'm looking for an alternative to `tcpflow` that supports UDP.
Specifically, a linux utility that reconstructs UDP packets from a pcap file into a single byte-stream.

Any suggestions?

Thanks